# Identifying properties of neigbouring elements in a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, numpy, matrix

Having a matrix which looks like this

```
9 9 1 9 9 9 9 1
9 9 1 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 1 9 9 9 9 9
9 9 9 9 9 1 1 1
9 9 9 9 9 1 9 9
9 9 9 1 9 9 9 9
9 9 1 9 1 9 9 9
```

I would like to detect for each position in the matrix, if there is at least a value `1` sorrounding the matrix in question such that for element in `{2, 2}` i want to check values in `{1,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,1}, {2,3}, {3,1}, {3,2}, {3,3}` and if any position mentioned contains 1, then i store the element in `{2,2}` in a seperate variable.

I do not know how to get by this and would like to know if there is any pythonic function or way that can do this?

Comment: [i downvoted your question because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) you do not show any effort you made.

Comment: I really have no idea how to do it and I need some assistance that is why I posted this

Comment: Here are a couple of posts to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13621651/1288 https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/178603/2105 Also, neighbor checking is a big component of Conway's Game of Life. You might check different implementations of that to see how it's done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take inspiration from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358340/matlab-sum-of-surrounding-elements) and use `conv2`

In MATLAB (you said "pythonic" but tagged MATLAB) this looks like the following:

```
numneighbours = conv2( A==1, [1 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1], 'same' );
```

Now you want any elements where `numneighbours > 0`

```
output = A(numneighbours > 0);
```

This could of course be done in 1 line.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3731624/3978545) suggests [`convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) is a Python equivalent to MATLAB's `conv2`.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is [dilating](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) a mask which indicates where the one values are, with a square 3x3 [structuring element](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel.html), as follows:

```
onesMask = mat==1;
res = imdilate(mask,strel('square',3)) & ~onesMask;
```

result:

```
 0     1     0     1     0     0     1     0
 0     1     0     1     0     0     1     1
 0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     1     1     1     1     1
 0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     1     1     0     1     1
 0     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
 0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0
```

Comment: Worth noting that `imdilate` requires the image processing toolbox in MATLAB.